# enabling guard malloc for Iphone device or for store kit api?

Tags: iphone, malloc, storekit, guard

I am using store kit api for an application on iphone. I would like to know if it is possible to enable Malloc Guard while running on the device and see if there are any memory leaks. Could someone let me know if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) doesn't mention it is possible, quoting:

> You can use this option both Mac OS X applications and also for iPhone applications running in the simulator.

So I guess it's a no-go on the device.